# Open votation to undelete question which has been deleted by a moderator

Tags: discussion

The following question has been deleted because I copied and pasted it: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7356/one-subdomain-is-not-working/67611#67611

I have edited it. I think it fits the rules now, but I can't undelete it because I was deleted by a moderator.

I can't write a new answer because the question is on hold.

Any suggestion or something I should know?

Comment: Only a moderator can un-delete a post deleted by a moderator. We cannot vote to undelete.

Comment: On a personal note, please don't take the actions of our moderators (including myself) as an indication that your contributions are not welcome here.   StackExchange sites have lots of rules decided through the community that are not apparent to newcomers.   I myself copied and pasted an answer among a handful of similar questions on a StackExchange site when I was newer.   Now I know that the correct thing to do is to flag all those questions as duplicate and put my answer in the original.

Comment: no problem @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Your answers come from the right place: you solved your problem, found other people that had similar issues, and tried to put your solution in a place where it will be found by others.   That fits perfectly with the StackExchange spirit.   Please continue in that vein and don't let all the rules get you down.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller. I will continue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have corrected the problem that caused a post to be deleted by a moderator, flag it, use a custom reason, and explain what you did.  A moderator will see the flag and make a decision.

Comment: OK. I did it. Thanks!